# Safely presenting stored TinyMCE data

Tags: php, html, tinymce, symfony-1.4

We are experiencing some difficulties presenting Emails sent and stored via the TinyMCE editor safely.

The content is embedded deep in a hierarchy of tables and divs, and seeing how TinyMCE has a habit of occasionally leaving behind an extra, say

```
</table>
```

that is bound to introduce significant instability to the html-structure of the site.

The site is running PHP (Symfony 1.4) and supports jQuery.

Now, I am completely aware that I might be approaching this with both the wrong mindset and tools, but I am simply trying to find a way to:
**Trap HTML, preventing a PHP-variable containing HTML tags of supplying spare end-tags and closing tags higher up in the hierarchy.**

How would you go about tackling this obstacle? I am aware of the

```
strip_tags($var)
```

PHP-function, but I want, as far as safety and stability allows it, to leave the HTML tags intact in order to present the Emails as close to their intended as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Usual way to solve this problem is storing your text in 2 database columns (for example `text` and `text_formatted`).

When you save text from WYSIWYG editor you should format your text and save to `text_formatted` (with some custom parsing function, which should close tags, delete some chars, etc. I think, there are some open-source parsing functions).

And then, in output, you should use formatted text